# How to set a minimum value for a cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

We use google sheets to do price updates for our websites. Sometimes there may be a typo that allows too low of a value and we want to avoid the possibilty of these kinds of errors. Ideally, looking for a way to set a minimum value allowed for an individual cell in google sheets.

Example:

Price = $22.50

We want to avoid mistakes like:

Price = $2.25

Is there a way to set a minimum price on this cell so that the value cannot be entered unless it is higher than say, $20 for this example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Use **Data > Data validation > Is greater than or equal to >** `20`.